# chroot ssh users

Tags: linux, ssh

I am using CentOS 7.

I need to give shell access to ssh users but restrict them in a jail.
I have used jailkit to set up the jail. I have copied all necessary libraries, binaries that are needed for the user in the jailed environment.

However, when the user logs in, he can cd into other directories in the jailed environment. I want the user to be restricted to his/her home directory and not be able to cd to any other directory.

I have tried to use the Match group directive in sshd_config but this is the error I get when I try to login through ssh after setting it:

`Could not chdir to home directory /var/jail/./home/user: No such file or directory
/usr/sbin/jk_chrootsh: No such file or directory`

and I can't login

I am really stuck here. I can't figure out how to resolve this problem. can someone please help? How can I restrict SSH users to their home directories in a jailed environment?

Comment: Have you forced them to use the rbash?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a configuration problem, not a security problem. It should be asked on [unix.se], but with more information, because it is unanswerable as is. Copy-paste your configuration files and provide all relevant information about the content of the jail directory tree.

Comment: @LvB rbash is a bit too strict

Comment: @Gilles i have posted the question with details in [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206245/chroot-ssh-users)